# Send location updates to Fragments from Host Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-gps

I have a Host Activity which uses ViewPager (Tabs) to display two Fragments.

Fragment A: Map Fragment that displays a user's current location along with location of friends (fetching from firebase).

Fragment B: With check box which when selected send's user's location to firebase for the friends to retrieve and view in their Fragment A.

I am currently implementing Location Manager's in both these fragments, however that doesn't feel right. What might be a better way to send location updates to these Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like implementing the location listener in the host `Activity`/Application then using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to pass the location to any activity/Fragment:

```
 // call this function in onLocationChanged. 
 EventBus.getDefault.post(new LocationUpdateEvent(updatedLocation));
```